# Default value for function parameter like range()

Tags: python

If I call range(1) in python the first argument is the 'max' argument of range. For range(1, 2, 3) the first argument is the 'min' argument of range. How would I define a function like range for myself where the meaning of the first argument depends on the count of all arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it something like this (using a `range` implementation as an example):

```
def range(start, stop=None, step=1):
   if stop is None:
       start, stop = 0, start
    while start < stop:
        yield start
        start += step
```

Comment: Kinda, except `range` has extra code to handle negative `step`.

Comment: Yeah, gotta swap the start and stop around in that case.

Comment: +1. My thought was to use `*args`, check the length, and `raise` if it was less than 1 or more than 3…I think this is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*args` and check the size of that:

```
def f(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        return "One argument shows the value: {}".format(args[0])
    elif len(args) == 2:
        return "Two arguments sums the values: {}".format(args[0] + args[1])
    return "Everything else does nothing"
```

which does:

```
>>> f()
'Everything else does nothing'
>>> f(0)
'One argument shows the value: 0'
>>> f(1, 1)
'Two arguments sums the values: 2'
>>> f(1, 2, 3)
'Everything else does nothing'
```

Comment: perfect! excactly what i searched for